# PHP Facebook FQL for query a public Note

Tags: php, facebook-like, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-fql

I have created an app with no special permissions. With this app I query Facebook events to display on my website. That all works fine.

I now wanted to expand the website with displaying Facebook Notes of my Fan Page. When I try to Implement that, I get the error message:

"Requires user session"

On the FQL-Note API reference they say "any valid access_token if it is public note written by a page." I think I have a valid public token.

```
require '../src/fb-sdk/src/facebook.php';

$facebooknotes = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'secret' => 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy',
    'cookie' => false, // enable optional cookie support
));

$fql_notes = "SELECT uid, note_id, title, content, content_html, created_time, updated_time FROM note WHERE uid = 149018831796518";

$param  =   array(
'method'    => 'fql.query',
'query'     => $fql_notes,
'callback'  => ''
);

$fql_notesResult   =   $facebooknotes->api($param);

foreach($fql_notesResult as $keys => $fbnotevalues){ echo "<h2>" . $fbnotevalues['title'] . "</h2>" . $fbnotevalues['content_html']; }
```

Can someone help?

Regards,

rimshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FQL does not seem to be able to get a page's notes. The `uid` field is looking for a user id. My guess is if you got the appropriate access token, you would still end up with an error because your ID does not belong to a page.

To get at the notes of a page, you need to use the graph API:

```
$fql_notesResult   =   $facebooknotes->api('/149018831796518/notes', 'GET');
foreach($fql_notesResult as $keys => $fbnotevalues){ 
  echo "<h2>" . $fbnotevalues['subject'] . "</h2>" . $fbnotevalues['message']; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. When I try using the Graph API I still get an error message: "Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: A user access token is required to request this resource".
From the facebook documentation I think that a "User Access Token" is not required for query this information.

Comment: I did a bit more research. This is a known bug. I've filed a repro against it. You should too. Of course, it's been known since 2012-02-13, so I'd work around it by storing one of your access tokens to use to make this query. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/354464304626449

Comment: Thanks for your research. I posted my repro now.